# Find the rational canonical form of a matrix from its minimal and characteristic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> What is the rational canonical form of $A$?
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
>     1       & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0       & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>     2      & 3 & -1 & 4\\
>    1     & 1 & -1 & 3\\
> \end{bmatrix}$$

I found that the minimal polynomial $m_A(x)=(x-1)^2$ and the characteristic polynomial $c_A(x)=(x-1)^4$. Therefore the invariant factors can be 
$$x-1,x-1,(x-1)^2$$
or
$$(x-1)^2,(x-1)^2$$
Therefore the rational canonical form may be
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0     & 0 & 0 & -1\\
  0    & 0 & 1 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
or
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0      & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1       & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0     & 0 & 0 & -1\\
  0    & 0 & 1 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I quickly figure out which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "first" $2\times 2$ principal block is clearly not an $x-1,x-1$ block as it is not the identity. Nor is the "other" $2\times 2$ principal block since it is not the identity. So we have two $(x-1)^2$ blocks.

Comment: Why the "first" $2\times 2$ principal block cannot be an $x-1,x-1$ block?

Comment: Surely the only matrix similar to the identity is the identity?

Answer (score 2):

If the first matrix is the rational form of $A$, we should have $\dim \ker (A - I) = 3$ (because this is true for the rational form and so it should be true for $A$ as well) while if the second matrix is the rational form of $A$, we should have $\dim \ker(A - I) = 2$. Just check which of those two options holds for $A$ by computing the rank of $A - I$.